# After calling inner AsyncTask class on button click code line below that execute before AsyncTask class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

I am calling a inner AsyncTask class whose name is `CallWebservice()`. I want to load data in in ArrayList and then want to show that data in a custom listview in second page by the help of intent. But my problem is that when I click on **btnSearchAreaWise** button the lines after new `CallWebservice().execute()` while excute and my control goes on second page without any data in Arraylist. But when I came back again and perform a second onClick on the same button now this time data is loaded in second page. I don't know what is going on. Please help.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   if (v == btnSearchAreaWise) {
      selectedAreaId = spinArea.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1;
      new CallWebservice().execute("GetDocListByArea");
      Intent i = new Intent(this, DoctorsList.class);
      startActivity(i);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write below code in the onPostExecute method of your CallWebservice Asyntask

```
Intent i=new Intent(this, DoctorsList.class);
            startActivity(i);
```

like this

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            try {
                Intent i=new Intent(this, DoctorsList.class);
                               startActivity(i);
                YourCurrentActivity.this.finish();

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
```

Offial documentation of [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

From The Android Docs

When an asynchronous task is executed, the task goes through 4 steps:

```
onPreExecute(), invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed. This step is normally used to setup the task, for instance by showing a progress bar in the user interface.

doInBackground(Params...), invoked on the background thread immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing. This step is used to perform background computation that can take a long time. The parameters of the asynchronous task are passed to this step. The result of the computation must be returned by this step and will be passed back to the last step. This step can also use publishProgress(Progress...) to publish one or more units of progress. These values are published on the UI thread, in the onProgressUpdate(Progress...) step.

onProgressUpdate(Progress...), invoked on the UI thread after a call to publishProgress(Progress...). The timing of the execution is undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the user interface while the background computation is still executing. For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in a text field.

onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background computation is passed to this step as a parameter.
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. I have made a little modification and it worked. just use the outer class that is my MainActivity.this on the place of this.                                                                                                           Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, DoctorsList.class);       startActivity(i);

Comment: Welcome, If this answer solved your query you should mark this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should start the new intent in onPostExecute method of the async class.